# javascript ("INPUT")[0] <-the [0] part on the code? can someone explain?

Tags: javascript

good day I am new to javascript and I don't understand what line of code is this?

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_setattribute).

```
document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].setAttribute("type", "button");
```

I don't understand why is there ("INPUT")[0] <-----the [0] part on the code? can someone explain?

appreciate

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a list of matched elements. `[0]` simply takes the first element in that list

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")` returns an array. Adding `[0]` references the first element of the array.

Comment: FWIW `document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")` is not an array, it's an `HTMLCollection`.

`Array.isArray(document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT"))` => `false`.

Comment: ok guys thank you :D .